# XSLT to convert CDATA into text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a complete novice when it comes to XSLT so am struggling to find a solution to my problem.

I have the following XML which comes from PeopleSoft:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <ConnectedQuery>
    <Employee key="3000862">
      <Empl_ID>
        <![CDATA[12345678]]>
      </Empl_ID>
      <Name>
        <![CDATA[John Doe]]>
      </Name>
      <Job key="12345678,0,2018-09-17,0">
        <Empl_ID>
          <![CDATA[12345678]]>
        </Empl_ID>
        <Empl_Record>0</Empl_Record>
        <Effective_Date>2018-09-17</Effective_Date>
        <Effective_Sequence>0</Effective_Sequence>
      </Job>
    </Employee>
  </ConnectedQuery>
</document>
```

PeopleSoft "helpfully" puts all text data into CDATA sections and I would like to remove the CDATA and have the strings in normal text nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
  <ConnectedQuery>
    <Employee key="3000862">
      <Empl_ID>12345678</Empl_ID>
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <Job key="12345678,0,2018-09-17,0">
        <Empl_ID>12345678</Empl_ID>
        <Empl_Record>0</Empl_Record>
        <Effective_Date>2018-09-17</Effective_Date>
        <Effective_Sequence>0</Effective_Sequence>
      </Job>
    </Employee>
  </ConnectedQuery>
</document>
```

Could someone please give me a steer in the right direction on the XSLT I need to create my desired output? Many thanks in advance

Comment: A simple *identity transform* will remove the CDATA markup. You may also want to add `normalize-space()` because the white space surrounding the CDATA blocks is part of the node's value.

Comment: So I've managed to get back to this after being pulled onto another project. The answer above appears to work... except in PeopleSoft! I'm not sure why that might be at the moment (other XLST I have used within PeopleSoft works as expected). Are there any other ways I could achieve the same thing that I could try in PS?

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with PeopleSoft, so I don't know. Why are the CDATA wrappers a problem to begin with? Any XML parser down the road should be able to handle the original XML as is.

Answer (score 0):

just run [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying), it will convert CDATA to normal string

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

see transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5E1